# Python Getters, Setters

Tags: python

```
class P:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

I am trying to learn 'getters' and 'setters' methods. 
When I create an instance with these inputs:

```
p1 = P(1001) 
print(p1.x)
p1.x = -12
print(p1.x)
```

I get as outputs:

```
1001
-12
```

I don't know why do I get `1001` and `-12` instead of `1000` and `0`.

Comment: Please fix your indentation: the code as you've shown it would only result in a syntax error.

Comment: you are mixing between self.x and self.__x

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue... I get 1000 and 0 (after fixing the indentation, so I suppose it could be an indentation issue somewhere).

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: OP is following this tutorial: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for your comment, I was unaware of indentation mistake, I fixed it.

Comment: @glibdud I am using Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your real problem is that you're using Python 2.x with old-style classes. Your code as shown will work as you expect on Python 3.x (except for the broken indentation, of course). It will also work on Python 2.x if you make `P` a new-style class by explicitly inheriting from `object` (e.g. declare it as `class P(object):`).

In an old-style class, the problem is that your setter and getter methods are both named `x`, and both are competing for entries in the same namespace.

When you have code like:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    ...
```

What happens is that a new function object (confusingly, named `x`) is created with the code you specify, then `x.setter(x_function_object)` is called, and whatever `x.setter` returns (which will be a descriptor object with `__get__` and `__set__` defined) is assigned to `x` in the namespace dictionary that is passed to the metaclass's `__new__` method and used to build the class's type.

However, in an old-style class, when you write `self.x = ...` then it will invoke `__setattr__` directly rather than using the descriptor protocol (`self.__dict__['x'].__set__(x, ...)`). Thus the assignment to `self.x` in your `__init__` method will overwrite the setter method instead of calling it.